Which movie did one character manage to vomit all the poison he swallowed
It's fantasy martial arts (e.g. some people can fly) with some comic touches here and there. The budget wasn't massive (not at the level of a Hero or a Crouching Tiger...) but it felt epic nevertheless. 
One of the masters, who (I think) was portrayed as wise and funny was fed poison, and on noticing, vomited it all out, and what was going on inside his bowels was portrayed with some rather poor visual effects.
I enjoyed this movie much, for I'm a sucker for oriental fantasy, but also because the movie had some powerful emotional moments (I remember there was some romance, complete with a gorgeous gal). I saw this movie within the last 15 years (can't remember when exactly).

I don't know which movie it is, but I might know something to help your search. There is a Chinese national hero, called Huo Yuan Jia, who lived late 1800's-early 1900's. He died from being poisoned. I believe there are several movies based on his character, one of them is "Fearless" where Jet Li portrayed Huo Yuan Jia. Another name/character that may be in the movie is Chen Zen, who was Huo Yuan Jia's kungfu student. Several movies were also based on him, amongst the one in Fist of Fury portrayed by Bruce Lee. p.s. fun fact: The sub-genre of wire-fu fantasy films you're looking for is called

The master, in this case, didn't die. He was also maybe in his 50's.

Looking at the wikipedia page, it appears that wuxia is rather too broad, since it also includes stories where the character's abilities are realistic.

Alright, i'll check out the meaning of 'wuxia' again some time, thx.

It is The Duel (2000). The scene I described happens very early in the movie. I found out because I bumped into a review of it which I wrote years ago. Oh, and a revisit didn't prove to be as great an experience.
